# Left click doesnt work after upgrade to 20.04 from bionic

Tags: upgrade, sound, mouse

touchpad click doesnt work anymore after 20.04 lts version.how can I solve it? also the sounds of laptops such as youtube etc. come only while headphone attached with pc.either, doesnt come sound from pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse

sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```